# uniform convergence of sequences of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functions, uniform-convergence

I'm trying to study this sequence of functions:

$f_n(x) = nxe^{-nx}$ for $x \in [0,1]$

i ended up with the

- **point convergence** -> $f(x) = 0$
- **uniform convergence** The function doesn't have the uniform convergence to $f(x) = 0$ in $[0, 1]$. Becouse during the study of the convergence if found that the $sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f_n(x) - f(x)| = \frac{1}{n}$ and for this $x=\frac{1}{n}$ the $\lim\limits_{n \to +inf}e^{-1} \not= 0$

I think that that's ok but I know that a correct and complete study of the sequences of functions include the analisys of the uniform convergence in other sub-ranges $[\alpha, \beta] ⊂ [0, 1]$. I don't know how to do this in a step-by-step way, but i think that in this case the uniform convergence is present in

$[0, a] ⊂ [0, 1]$ with $a<\frac{1}{n}$

$[b, 1] ⊂ [0, 1]$  with $b>\frac{1}{n}$

where $\frac{1}{n}$ is the max value assumed by the function at index $n$ of the sequence. Am i right or thats a wrong idea?

Comment: The domain where you want uniform convergence must not depend on $n$. Here it will work in $[b, 1]$ if $b>0$.

Comment: @Gribouillis If  the only condition is $b>0$ at some point wouldn't I have to considere also $\frac{1}{n}$ ( that the convergence is not uniform if this point is in the considered range ) ?

Comment: $1/n$ is not a specific point. It is a different point for every function $f_n$ in the sequence.

Comment: Yet another thread closed for bad reasons.

Comment: @Gribouillis Yeah i got it, but i'm not understanding the idea behind the your affermation that the considered range where the convergence is uniform is $[b, 0]$ with $b>0$. Is that becouse $\lim\limits_{n \to +inf}\frac{1}{n} = 0$ and so when $n $ goes to infinity i have only to put $b > 0$ becouse this contidion will exclude the point $\frac{1}{n}$ ? Or i'm totally missing the point?

Comment: I'm not saying it is *the* range where the convergence is uniform. I'm only saying that it is *a* range where this happens. Another one is $[0.5, 0.73]$. No such range however contains an interval such as $[0,a]$ where $a>0$

Comment: @Gribouillis ok, it is a range, but why you can say that in $[0, a]$ there is no uniform converngence instead in $[b, 0]$ with $b>0$ yes, that's where i miss the point, i mean what is the condition thet make you do that affermation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116330/discussion-between-gribouillis-and-mat-c).